# How to retrieve multiple picture from firebase using Map function

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5ox6.png)

I have a problem where I cannot retrieve my pictures in form of image slider using the map function.

[here, is my database and cars details]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1akkc.png)retrieving data using map and snapshot

```
collectdata((Map<String,Object>)dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

All the data will be insert in in arrayList like this. however, I am not sure if my images retrieving code is true or not:

```
 private void collectdata(Map<String, Object> value) {
    int count = 0;
   for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : value.entrySet()){

       Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
       //Object n = new Object (arrPic1.toArray(new String[0]),arrPic2.toArray(new String[1]),arrPic3.toArray(new String[2]) ,arrPic4.toArray(new String[3]) ,arrPic5.toArray(new String[4]));

        arrTrans.add((String) singleUser.get("mCarTransmission")); //tarik dari db
        arrBrand.add((String) singleUser.get("mCarBrand"));
        arrModel.add((String) singleUser.get("mCarModel"));
        arrMileage.add((String) singleUser.get("mCarMileage"));
        arrPrice.add((String) singleUser.get("mCarPrice"));
        arrYear.add((String) singleUser.get("mCarYearManufacturing"));
        arrName.add((String) singleUser.get ("mCarName"));
        arrVariant.add((String) singleUser.get ("mCarVariant"));
        arrPic1.add((String)singleUser.get("image1"));
        arrPic2.add((String)singleUser.get("image2"));
        arrPic3.add((String)singleUser.get("image3"));
        arrPic4.add((String)singleUser.get("image4"));
        arrPic5.add((String)singleUser.get("image5"));

        final String[] img = new String[]{"arrPic1","arrPic2","arrPic3","arrPic4","arrPic5"};
```

then, i pass in in arraylist.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(choose.this, Result.class);

                intent.putExtra("Name", mCarName.get(count).toString());
                intent.putExtra("Transmission", mCarTransmission.get(count).toString());
                intent.putExtra("Brand", mCarBrand.get(count).toString());
                intent.putExtra("MileAge", mCarMileage.get(count).toString());
                intent.putExtra("Price", mCarPrice.get(count).toString());
                intent.putExtra("Year", mCarYearManufacturing.get(count).toString());
                intent.putExtra("Variant", mCarVariant.get(count).toString());
                intent.putExtra("Pic1", image1.get(count).toString());
                intent.putExtra("Pic2", image2.get(count).toString());
                intent.putExtra("Pic3", image3.get(count).toString());
                intent.putExtra("Pic4", image4.get(count).toString());
                intent.putExtra("Pic5", image5.get(count).toString()) String[] abc = new String[]{"Pic1","Pic2","Pic3","Pic4","Pic5"};
                            Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
                            bundle.putStringArray("abc",abc);
                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                            data = true;
```

Here, to retrieve the data to next activity:

```
   String[] abc = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("abc");

    name.setText(a);
    brandd.setText(b);
    terans.setText(c);
    mileagee.setText(d);
    pricee.setText(e);
    ym1.setText(f);
    v.setText(g);

    //swipe image
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(Result.this,abc); //Here we are defining the Imageadapter object
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); // Here we are passing and setting the adapter for the images
    //return connectedUser.get(0);
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code?

Comment: im dont know how to retrieve multiple image using the map. all the details can be retrieved but image cant

Comment: What do you mean `all the details can be retrieved but image cant`?

Comment: for example, i have add 5 images of car, car name, car brand, car mileage, car trasmission, and car price in the firebase. All the data can be retrieved from the firebase. however, the images cannot be retrieved in form of image slider. can you explain why my images cannot be retrieved.

Comment: I understand now, please add your database structure,

Comment: Please add it in your question and not as a comment.

Comment: i already uploaded the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
String[] abc = new String[]{"Pic1","Pic2","Pic3","Pic4","Pic5"};
```

to

```
String[] abc = new String[]{
    image1.get(count).toString(),
    image2.get(count).toString(),
    image3.get(count).toString(),
    image4.get(count).toString(),
    image5.get(count).toString()
};
```

You actually need to store the String values of those urls and not the literal strings: "Pic1" to "Pic5"               .